# How to prevent colliders from stopping each other while colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I am working on a 3D unity project, which I have a platform in it and a character who runs on that platform, I placed the character on the platform but it started to fall down so I solved the problems by following these steps:

1. added a capsule collider to the object, it still fall through the platform
2. added a collider to the platform, then it didn't fall down but now these two objects are soled to each other so the character is just moving her legs in the same place,

Is there any way to make the character move on the platform while still using colliders?

Note 1: I made the collider trigger in the image to make the same exact behaviour with out colliders.

Note 2: I tried to put each one of them on a different layer but I get the same problem.

code:

```
void Update () 
{
    rbody.velocity = new Vector3(rbody.velocity.x,0f,playerVelocity*Time.deltaTime);

    rbody.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
                     .
                     .
                     .
}
```

[image]

Comment: in the image it seems that your player is stuck in the middle of the street, can you try to put him on top of of the street "manually" and see if it works?

Comment: The image is just to show that the object is diving when the colllider is trigger but it is stuck now because of the collisions

Answer (score 1):

Making the collider trigger is like adding no collider. Trigger is only used when you want the collider to detect something but not stop it from running into things. So I believe you should add a non-trigger collider to both the character and the platform but make sure that the colliders are not intersecting when you put the character manually at first. If that didn't work, tell me exactly the coordinates of the character and the platform and the sizes of their colliders and I will try to replicate your scene to figure out the problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: I removed the isCollider now it is false

Comment: Are the size of the Collider and the mass of the objects matters?

Comment: You mean you removed "isTrigger"?

Comment: No, the collider size or mass doesn't matter in your situation.

Comment: Yes I removed it and now the objects are solid to each others

Comment: And the character is not moving

Comment: Well I replicated your scene and added this code to the character, it worked.

Comment: `using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Walking : MonoBehaviour {

 Rigidbody rbody;
 float z;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
  z = transform.position.z;;
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  z += 0.5f;
  rbody.velocity = new Vector3(rbody.velocity.x,0f,10*Time.deltaTime);
  rbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z));

  rbody.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
 }
}`

Comment: You just need to add this line: 
`rbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z));`
Where z is increased every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend you have 2 options...

1. Change the mass of your RigidBody
2. Use PhysicsMaterial and reduce the friction between the objects (Add a Physic Material to your Platform)
3. Increase the force and movement speed in your script.